# CakePHP 3 Model Form Send Email with User submitted attachment

Tags: cakephp

These are the results from when I do debug($this->request->data)

I ommited the fields that didn't matter

I get this

```
[
'file' => 'Atest.doc'
]
```

I want this

```
[
'file' => [
    'tmp_name' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpgBEFye',
    'error' => (int) 0,
    'name' => 'Atest.doc',
    'type' => 'application/msword',
    'size' => (int) 45056
]
```

Here is .ctp

```
 echo $this->Form->create($contact, ['id'=>'contact-form']);
 echo $this->Form->file('file', ['label'=> 'Cover Letter']);
 echo $this->Form->button('Send');
 echo $this->Form->end();
```

My Contact Controller

```
 <?php
 namespace App\Controller;
 use App\Controller\AppController;
 use App\Form\ContactForm;
 use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
 use Cake\Mailer\Email;
 use Cake\Network\Exception\SocketException;

 use Burzum\FileStorage\Storage\StorageManager;

public function index($option = 'index'){
       $contact = new ContactForm();
       if ($this->request->is('post')) {


           if ($contact->execute($this->request->getData())) {
            //debug($this->request->getData() );
            }
        } 
  ///..I omitted the rest
}
```

Comment: **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-file-inputs**

Comment: yea i figured it after after i posted it, it was 
echo $this->Form->create($document, ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $this->Form->create($document, ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']);
```